# Dynamic Carousel with indicators

Tags: flutter, carousel

I'm developing flutter application in which I want to add Sliding Carousel with indicators and that should be dynamic. So, anyone can help out.

I have tried to implement from [Carousel Slider](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider) but there is no indicator support.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, why don't you build your own widget using a Stack combined with the carousel slider?

Regarding creating the dots, you can use the [`dots_indicator`](https://pub.dev/packages/dots_indicator) package.

Here is a complete working example:

```dart
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:dots_indicator/dots_indicator.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Demo',
      home: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var _currentIndex = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _data = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'];
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(children: [
        CarouselSlider(
          items: _data.map((e) {
            return Container(
              color: Colors.green,
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  e,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 100),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
          options: CarouselOptions(
            height: 400,
            viewportFraction: 1,
            onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
              setState(() {
                _currentIndex = index;
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          bottom: 30,
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          child: Center(
            child: DotsIndicator(
              dotsCount: _data.length,
              position: _currentIndex,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]